# Cannot use reuse Salesforce object for SF Data Entry in Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

According to the [SF documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5), we should be able to reference a given object in up to 80 Journeys using "Salesforce Data" as the entry data however, I have noticed the object is not available if it's used by a single journey already. Is this a bug?

Comment: if I understand correctly that would mean you could not create two journeys, one starting on campaign member status = "new" and one on campaign member status = "sent". if this is truly the case, it sure sounds like a bug.

Comment: Yep this is correct, will reach out to SF support in that case.